# scraping though Coursera pages using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the list of coursers offered by coursera. I am interested in teh results of the first 10 pages. However, I am only able to scrape the first page.

I am using the library Beautifulsoup.this is part of teh code which gets results for the first page:

```
url = "https://www.coursera.org/courses"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

I tried to accede the next pages by modifying the URL, but nothing works. I tried "page=" and several other combinations. Any idea of how I can browse through the remaining pages?

(using the API is not an option)

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried to accede the next pages by modifying the URL, but nothing works. I tried "page=" and several other combinations. Any idea of how I can browse through the remaining pages?

Comment: Why using their API is *not* an option?

Comment: @baduker I've tried that but I got status code as 400. How can I avoid that? I shared my code and I also used headers user-agent,accept,accept-language,referer... result didn't changed(400)

Comment: `import json
url = 'https://lua9b20g37-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.30.0%3Breact-instantsearch%205.2.3%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.1&x-algolia-application-id=LUA9B20G37&x-algolia-api-key=dcc55281ffd7ba6f24c3a9b18288499b'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
js = json.loads(r.text)
print(js)`

Comment: @baduker I tried replicating a request similar to Elkhan's from my network logs with [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/python/) but the request was taking over 10min before I interrupted. Is there another API that can be used?

Comment: @Elkhan you might need to try selenium

Comment: i hate selenium ( damn. @ Driftr95